# apt install package ignoring version

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to write a bash script to build a few packages from source, to run on fresh installs of different debian-based os's (armbian, mx, etc). There are several libboost dependencies, and just about any version of libboost will work. The problem is that different distros have different versions of libboost, and libboost packages have the major version in the package name (eg., 'libboost-thread1.72-dev'). How do I specify the package without specifying the version so the bash script will work regardless of the distro? I tried libboost-thread1.??-dev but that doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

luckily, there's the [boost-defaults](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/boost-defaults) packages that provide dependencies on the default version of a given boost-package.

e.g. the following will install `libboost-thread-dev`, which in turn will install `libboost-thread1.71-dev` on my current Debian/sid (aka Debian/unstable)  machine, but `libboost-thread1.67-dev` on Raspbian/buster (the current stable release of Raspbian):

```
apt install libboost-thread-dev
```